# Eclipse Mars won't start on ArchLinux with Gnome

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, eclipse

I am trying to install Eclipse Mars on my ArchLinux, but the application won't start. I use gnome as my desktop environement.

So I tried to launch it in console:

```
eclipse -debug -consolelog
```

the log stop after this lines:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Starting application: 1954
```

My cpu run at background(30%) and it took 1G  of nemory, but no application showed

I tried to download Eclipse Mars from the website but I had the same problem. I tried it with eclipse Luna and that worked, but I need to use eclipse Mars.

How can I start Eclipse Mars on ArchLinux?

Comment: Does `eclipse -clean` work? You might need to run it as root if you have plugins installed by root.

Comment: no `eclispe -clean` don't work

Comment: I installed eclipse from the Arch repository and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. This didn't come form Eclipse Mars.

I used Gnome on wayland like desktop environement. I used that because my touchpad didn't work on Gnome. I folow instruction form this [website](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/3b7g2b/gnome_touchpad_not_working_under_gnome_but_gdm/) To solve the touchpad problem:

> I installed xf86-input-libinput drivers.

So, now I use Gnome and that's work. Thank for your help Thomas Dickey